# logica para calculo de tempo medio de ligação em segundos

Tags: javascript

por exemplo: Um assistente de telemarketing atende 50 ligações em um dia. porem há uma meta de 330 segundo por ligação, que é 6 minutos no máximo.
O que eu quero fazer é um algorítimo onde eu consiga colocar o tempo da ligação no input, depois calcular a media com base na primeira ligação, conforme eu fosse adicionando os próximos minutos de ligações, iria somar com base no numero de vezes que eu colocasse a quantidade de minutos de ligação. eu ja fiz algo, parece eficiente mas a questao da soma ser relativa a quantas vezes eu adiciono o tempo das ligações nao funciona, porem me ajudar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>calculo de TMO</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
   
      <div class="centro">
          tempo de ligação van gogh:
          <input class="tempo" type="text"><br>
        
          <button onclick="clicar()">calcular</button>
          <p class="calcular"></p>
      
      </div>
  
  </section>
  <script>
    
      function clicar(){
          var tempo = document.querySelector(".tempo").value;
          var resultado = 0;
          for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
          resultado = parseInt(tempo) * i * 60 /  i ;
          }
          document.querySelector(".calcular").innerHTML = resultado;
      }
      
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tá difícil entender o que quer. Melhora ai seu português.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que pude entender, você quer calcular a media das ligações, e cada vez que você clica em adicionar, você quer calcular a media e mostrar ela certo?
Primeiro adicionei um algumas coisas a mais para ter um melhor output para ficar mais bonito

```
 <div class="centro">
      tempo de ligação van gogh em segundos:
      <input class="tempo" type="text"><br>
    
      <button onclick="clicar()">calcular</button>
      <p>Foram efetuadas: <span class="numeroLigacoes">0</span> ligações </br>A media de tempo é: <span class="calcular">0</span> segundos. ou <span class="minutos">0</span> minutos. ou <span class="horas">0</span> horas</p>
  
  </div>
```

No javascript, realmente n consigo entender a logica que você esta fazendo no seu codigo, mas se for para calcular a media das ligações, você vai precisar botar todas as ligações em um array, soma-las e depois dividir pelo numero de ligações existentes no array.

```
var tempo_medio_segundos = 0;
var ligacoes = [];
    function clicar(){
        var tempo = document.querySelector(".tempo").value; //Pega o valor do input
        ligacoes.push(tempo); //Joga ele dentro de um array
        var media = 0; //Limpa a variavel media
        for (let i = 0; i < ligacoes.length; i++) {
            media = media + parseInt(ligacoes[i]); //Soma todas as ligações
        }
        tempo_medio_segundos = media / ligacoes.length; //Divide essa soma para ter a media
        tempo_medio_segundos.toFixed(1); //Não me lembro da função que faz isso, mas em teoria essa função corta os numeros depois da virgula
        document.querySelector(".calcular").innerHTML = tempo_medio_segundos;
        document.querySelector(".minutos").innerHTML = tempo_medio_segundos / 60; //conversao segundos para minutos
        document.querySelector(".horas").innerHTML = (tempo_medio_segundos / 60) / 60; //conversao segundos para horas
        document.querySelector(".numeroLigacoes").innerHTML = ligacoes.length; //quantas ligações foram efetuadas
    }
```

O valor do array deve ser declarado fora da função para que quando for executada, não "resete" o valor dele.
O input deve ser em segundos.
Caso esse código seja totalmente o contrario do que você desejava, por favor reformule a questão para melhor entendimento.
Caso tenha resolvido seu problema, boa noite, se tiver qualquer outra duvida só chamar :)